# Visual Studio 2015 Modify and add Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10240 is taking too long

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 on a new Windows 10 computer, but I didn't install new SDK for Windows Universal apps and other projects- like cross platform mobile development like Cordova.

After trying to install those parts in modify installed sections on `Add/remove programs or features`, it starts normally but takes very long time to go forward. It seemed like it is stuck installing those features.

[image]

I suspected that it uses internet sources to install these features, and I have a very slow internet connection. Could this be related to my slow connection ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, programming-related questions are off topic on Super User, so this may be at risk of being closed. That said, Visual Studio finished "aquiring" the SDK, and is now "applying" it. Assuming there is some activity, I would just wait and see if it progresses.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any suggestions to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is taking time because it is downloading the SDK. Even though the `Acquiring` bar is 100%, it still downloads the SDK while `Applying` it.

Open Resource Monitor (`Task Manager > Performance > Open Resource Monitor`) and see the `Network` tab. A process `sdksetup.exe` (located at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudioSecondaryInstaller\14.0\installers\Win10SDK_Hidden_10.0.10240\en\0\sdksetup.exe`) will be receiving lot of data.

Comment: I could not see sdksetup.exe exactly, but thank you for letting me know. I was sitting in a corner of house where wifi is spotty. I went right back near wifi after reading this. :D

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's downloading the required assets. I had this problem too when you turn on Airplane mode the installer fails.
It's very maddening that 4 GBs of Visual Studio installer doesn't include Windows 10 SDK.